# How can filtered count() operation in PostgreSQL be turned into criteria builder?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have the tables below;

**batch** table: id, name, description, create_timestamp, created_by ...

**batch_run** table: id, batch_id, ...

**journey** table: id, batch_id, ...

**booking** table: id, journey_id, status, ...

**segment** table: id, journey_id, departure_time, ...

**item** table: id, booking_id, passenger_uuid

How can I use filtered count() operation in java criteria builder? Because in the end, I will convert this query into criteria builder.

```
select
    batch.id,
    batch."name",
    batch.description,
    batch.create_timestamp,
    batch.created_by,
    COUNT(distinct b.id) as bookingCount,
    COUNT(distinct j.id) as distinctJourneyCount,
    COUNT(distinct b.status) FILTER(WHERE b.status = 'succeeded') as succeedBookingCount,
    COUNT(distinct b.status) FILTER(WHERE b.status = 'failed') as failedBookingCount,
    COUNT(distinct b.status) FILTER(WHERE b.status = 'skipped') as skippedBookingCount,
    COUNT(distinct b.status) FILTER(WHERE b.status = 'unprocessed') as unprocessedBookingCount,
    COUNT(distinct i.passenger_uuid) as distinctPassengerCount,
    MIN(s.departure_time) as minimumDepartureTime,
    MAX(s.departure_time) as mmaximumDepartureTime, 
    batch.status 
from
    batch
left join journey j on
    batch.id = j.batch_id
left join segment s on
    j.id = s.journey_id
left join booking b on
    j.id = b.journey_id
left join item i on
    b.id = i.booking_id
left join batch_run br on
    batch.id = br.batch_id
group by
    batch.id;
```

Comment: `CriteriaBuilder` has methods `count` and `countDistinct` that take an expression.

Comment: @RobSpoor I put the column that I want to count into countDistinct. However I don't know how to add the condition to this ?

cb.countDistinct(joinBooking.get(Booking_.status))

Comment: Right, the FILTER function. That looks to be a Postgres specific function. To support that directly probably requires you to use the `function` method. However, I'm not sure this structure is possible. An alternative is to not use `COUNT` but instead use a subquery: `(SELECT COUNT(...) FROM ... WHERE ...) as columnName`. I don't know how that impacts performance.

Comment: @RobSpoor my intention was to use subquery as you mentioned but joined tables cannot be reached from subqueries so I don't know what to add to WHERE condition otherwise subquery will produce the same result for each batch.

Comment: I think that in this case, switching to `CriteriaBuilder` will limit you more than it's worth. Is there a reason you need to use `CriteriaBuilder`? Why not keep this as a native query?